# Intent ACTION.VIEW fails

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-contentprovider, android-search

I've recently created search-suggestions but right now am I facing one strange issue. In searchable.xml did I set `android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"` and in Manifest did i put

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter> to a activity, which I want to open when the click on suggestion is performed.
```

The result is that it opens another activity - activity, where i show results, when the query is submitted and where is put this intent filter `<intent-filter> ...SEARCH /> </intent-filter>`

Is there any way, how to open different activity, when the suggestion is clicked?

My **AndroidManifest.xml** - check the //notes

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <provider
                    android:authorities="com.example.animalist.SuggestionProvider"
                    android:name=".SuggestionProvider" >
                </provider>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".SearchActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.animalist.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                       android:value=".SearchActivity"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.animalist.MoreActivity" //I want to open this
            android:label="@string/title_activity_more"       //activity when is the
            android:launchMode="singleTop"                     //suggestion clicked
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.animalist.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.animalist.MainActivity" />


             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.animalist.SearchActivity" //Activity which shows
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search"       //results, when the
            android:launchMode="singleTask"                   //query is submitted
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.animalist.MainActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" > //but also appears on sugg. click
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.animalist.MainActivity" />



            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>



            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        </activity>

    </application>
```

my **searchable.xml**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.animalist.SuggestionProvider" 
        android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
        android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
```

my **SuggestionProvider.java**

```
public class SuggestionProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String TAG = "SuggestionProvider";

    private static final int SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS = 1;

    private static final UriMatcher sURLMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        sURLMatcher.addURI("*", SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,
                SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS);
        sURLMatcher.addURI("*", SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*",
                SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = new String[] {
            "_id",
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY
    };

    public SuggestionProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projectionIn, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {
        int match = sURLMatcher.match(url);
        switch (match) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS:
                String query = url.getLastPathSegment();
                MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);

                ParseQuery<Animal> squery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);
            try {

                List<Animal> results = squery.find();
                for (Animal animal : results) {
                        addRow(cursor,  animal.getAnimal());
            } }catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return cursor;}
        return null;
                }





    private void addRow(MatrixCursor cursor, String string) {
        long id = cursor.getCount();
        cursor .newRow().add(id).add(string).add(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH).add(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri url) {
        int match = sURLMatcher.match(url);
        switch (match) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS:
                return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL: " + url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri url, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("update not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri url, ContentValues initialValues) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("insert not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri url, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("delete not supported");
    }
}
```

Comment: why extends ContentProvider { instead of extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider{

Comment: I can provide custom suggestions vith recentquerysuggestionadapter?